# Is there an Azure DevOps task to automatically deploy a new AWS Lambda *docker image*?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, azure-devops, aws-lambda-containers

I have an AWS Lambda function that runs a Docker image I create in Azure Devops.

My Azure DevOps Pipeline contains a Docker build task, and then an `ECRPushImage` task to push that image to AWS.

Currently, after pushing a new image, I have to go to the Lambda function's page and click on "Deploy new image" so the function updates and switches to the newly pushed image.

Can I automatize this step in AWS DevOps? I know of the `LambdaDeployFunction` task in the AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps, but it seems that this task's configuration can only handle deploying zip files, either stored locally or on S3 (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-azure-devops/blob/6664bb35be0ee8f2680e5118f6a6116a127ae5be/src/tasks/LambdaDeployFunction/TaskParameters.ts#L15)).

If that is not possible, what would be the best way to do that last step (i.e. deploying the new docker image to Lambda) from within AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using AWS CLI by running the following command.

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  my-function \
    --image-uri ecr-image-uri
```

In **Azure DevOps**, you can use [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/aws-cli.html) task to run the above command.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this immediately worked!